# Error de envio de correos con smtp.gmail.com en servidor Azure sobre código laravel

Tags: laravel, azure, email

El problema se presentó en un momento dado sin un razón obvia, hasta el momento la cuenta de correo funciona bien y el código no ha sufrido cambios. Leí un poco sobre el problema y en algunos foros aluden a que puede ser algún bloqueo por parte del servicio de Azure.

> **Nota**: El programa es una mesa de ayuda, la cual envía correos de
>   notificación al usuario que realiza la petición y al administrador de
>   casos, el error se presenta en el envío de correos, ya que los casos
>   quedan registrados y se pueden cerrar.
>
> Adicional probe con otros correos y puertos, pero sigue dando el mismo error.

El código de error que arroja la pagina es muy extenso, pero las primeras líneas de código muestran lo siguiente:

**Error**

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]
>
> at Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() in
>   StreamBuffer.php (line 62)
>
> at Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(array('protocol' => 'ssl',
>   'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com', 'port' => 465, 'timeout' => 30, 'blocking'
>   => 1, 'tls' => false, 'type' => 1, 'stream_context_options' => array())) in AbstractSmtpTransport.php (line 113)

Comment: Hola Diego. Trata de mejorar la explicación de lo que quieres hacer, lo que has intentado (con ejemplos) y qué problemas exactos tienes. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por agregar más información @Diego. No obstante, creo que aún falta un poco como para que alguien pueda intentar responder tu pregunta... Deberías etiquetar como Laravel... ¿Qué parte del código es la que está disparando el error? ¿Podrías publicar el fragmento relevante? ¿Cuál es el error completo que te da el intento de conexión? ¿Intentaste depurarlo, qué hiciste? ¿Intentaste aislar la parte del código que hace la conexión y enviar algún dato de prueba? ¿Intentaste conectarte a gmail desde algún otro cliente con el mismo protocolo y puerto?

Comment: Seria bueno conocer el error de SMTP (o sea el error al intentar conectarse) alli veremos el codigo del error de SMTP y es mas facil diagnosticar el problema. Pero dale una mirada a la config de la cuenta de Gmail es porque debes habilitar [Permitir que aplicaciones menos seguras accedan a las cuentas](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=es) y alli recien podras desde una app enviar a traves de SMTP de Gmail. (ya que no lo comentas seria bueno verificar)